# A More Efficient Way of Calculating Objective Function Value is Needed

Tags: matlab, matrix

I encountered a problem where my way of calculating the objective function is not efficient enough when it comes to a huge number of data (population size). (Scroll down if you feel the explanation is too long)

Matrix 'A' is of size nx1 where n is the number of facilities. The element in each row represents the length of the facilities respectively. For example:

```
A = [0.05          % 1    % Original Position
    0.03           % 2
    0.06           % 3
    0.04           % 4
    0.02];         % 5
```

Matrix 'W' is an upper triangular square matrix of size n containing the flow between facilities. For example:
(i.e. from facility 1 to 3 the flow is 4, same to 3 to 1)

```
W = [0     5     2     4     1
     0     0     3     0     2
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     5
     0     0     0     0     0];
```

I need to find the best arrangement in a row such that the objective function value is minimized.

[image: Objective Function]...............................................(1)

where w_ij is the flow between facilities and B_ij is the distance between the center of 2 facilities.

For example, the arrangement of facility is [2 4 1 5 3], so matrix A permutes to be

```
A = [0.03          % 2   % Permuted Position
    0.04           % 4
    0.05           % 1
    0.02           % 5
    0.06];         % 3
```

the distance between center of 4th and 3rd facility, B_13 = 0.05/2 + 0.02 + 0.06/2 = 0.0750 with flow value 2 based on matrix W.

---

---

Now, given the set of data p, a permutation matrix of m x n. Where m is the number of population and n is the number of facilities. Each row stores the arrangement of the facilities. For example:

```
p = [3     2     1     5     4                 % can be any number of row and column.
     5     4     1     2     3                 % in this case m = 3 (Since it has 3 rows)
     1     2     3     4     5];
```

So far, this is the objective function that I can think of (also some guide from member of stack overflow). The aim of this objective function is to return their values based on equation (1). You may refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27085618/4283034), in order to know what it did for each iteration in for loops.

```
function fit_value = fit_func(p,A,W,m)     % m is the number of rows
fit_value = zeros(1,m);
A2 = A(p);
for i=1:m
    W2 = W(p(i,:),p(i,:));
    end_pts = cumsum(A2(i,:));
    start_pts = end_pts - A2(i,:);
    start_dist = abs(bsxfun(@minus,start_pts,start_pts'));
    end_dist = abs(bsxfun(@minus,end_pts,end_pts'));
    distance = (start_dist + end_dist)./2;
    fit_value(i) = sum(sum(distance .* W2));
end
```

However, the data are huge for the function to be called each time (where the function may be called for many times as well). It has to loop for m times in order to get the fit_value. Is there any trick instead of using the 'for' loop?

---

---

---

Overall (For those who skip the explanation)

```
% Take this 4 Parameter
A = [0.05
    0.03
    0.06
    0.04
    0.02];

W = [0     5     2     4     1
     0     0     3     0     2
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     5
     0     0     0     0     0];

p = [3     2     1     5     4 
     5     4     1     2     3 
     1     2     3     4     5];

m = 3; % since p have 3 rows.

%  Substitute into this function
function fit_value = fit_func(p,A,W,m)     % m is the number of rows
fit_value = zeros(1,m);
A2 = A(p);
for i=1:m                                  % this for loop consume the time very much
    W2 = W(p(i,:),p(i,:));
    end_pts = cumsum(A2(i,:));
    start_pts = end_pts - A2(i,:);
    start_dist = abs(bsxfun(@minus,start_pts,start_pts'));
    end_dist = abs(bsxfun(@minus,end_pts,end_pts'));
    distance = (start_dist + end_dist)./2;
    fit_value(i) = sum(sum(distance .* W2));
end

% Will Return This Output
fit_value = [1.100    1.1400    1.6100];
```

What is the trick instead of using for loop, in order to have high efficient code?

Comment: A is not valid Matlab syntax. The semicolon in the last line should be after the 5, right?

Comment: @Unapiedra, thank for remind, actually that part is let reader easier to understand my problem. I edited by putting '%' in front of them.

Comment: What actually changes on each for each call of your objective function and what is constant?

Comment: @horchler, only the matrix p is kept changing for each call to the objective function. The rest A,W,m are constant.